# Time Compare SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am getting the current system time with the following query

```
select cast(DATEPART(hh,getdate()) as varchar)+ ':'+ cast(DATEPART(n,getdate()) as varchar)
```

Now how do I compare this current system time with a time field to see which is larger?

```
 -----------------------
 declare    @time1  datetime,
            @time2  datetime

 select  @time1 = '20060701 02:27:35.35',
         @time2 = getdate()

 select tm1, tm2,
        case    
         when tm1 = tm2 then 'tm1 = tm2' 
         when tm1 > tm2 then 'tm1 > tm2'
    else        'tm1 < tm2'
    end as [TimeDiff]
 from
 (
     select dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, @time1), @time1) as tm1,
            dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, @time2), @time2) as tm2
 ) t

 -----------------------
```

The time field has time in the following format

```
     0400
     0415
     0430
```

I see this supporting Function. Now how do I alter the @time1 part to "select time from table"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select case when cast(cast(DATEPART(hh,getdate()) as varchar)+ ':'+ cast(DATEPART(n,getdate()) as varchar) as datetime) >
       cast(left('0415',2)+':'+right('0415',2) as datetime) then 'greter' else 'lesser'
       end
```

Comment: Thanks.....I get this message "Type time is not a defined system type". Database in use is SQL Server

Comment: which version of sql you are using sql server 2005?

Comment: Yes.Sorry for not specifying

Comment: Thanks....can I also get Lesser and same  ? . Also the data I want to get from a table field as specified in the question

Comment: you can replcae '0415' with your field name

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace @time1 with a table column. In that case, here you go,

```
declare    @time2  datetime

CREATE Table #temp
(
time1 varchar(100)

)
Insert into #temp 
 select '20060701 02:27:35.35'

Insert into #temp 
 select '20060701 12:27:35.35'

 Insert into #temp 
 select '20060701 22:27:35.35'

 Select   @time2 = getdate()

 select tm1, tm2,
        case    
         when tm1 = tm2 then 'tm1 = tm2' 
         when tm1 > tm2 then 'tm1 > tm2'
         else        'tm1 < tm2'
        end as [TimeDiff]
 from
 (
     select dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, time1), time1) as tm1,
            dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, @time2), @time2) as tm2

        FROM #temp
 ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @time varchar(10)
SET @time='0400'
select CASE when convert(datetime,left(@time,2)+':'+RIGHT(@time,2))>convert(datetime,cast(DATEPART(hh,getdate()) as varchar)+ ':'+ cast(DATEPART(n,getdate()) as varchar)) then '1' else '0' end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the time like this:

```
select replace(cast(cast(getdate() as time) as varchar(5)), ':', '')
```

It gets the first 5 characters from the time and then removes the :.

Comment: Thanks.....I get this message "Type time is not a defined system type". Database in use is SQL Server

Comment: Oh, I ran this on SQL Server 2008. You probably are on a lower version. But you can use your initial query and then remove the :-sign so you can compare the two times.

Answer (score 0):

To get the time in that format is

```
select REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,108), ':', '')
```